# How to split a string on commas or periods in nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I want to separate a string on commas and/or periods in nltk. I've tried with `sent_tokenize()` but it separates only on periods.

I've also tried this code

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktLanguageVars
ex_sent = "This is an example showing sentence filtration.This is how it is done, in the case of Python I want to learn more. So, that I can have some experience over it, by it I mean Python."
class CommaPoint(PunktLanguageVars):
    sent_end_chars = ('.','?','!',',')
tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(lang_vars = CommaPoint())
n_w=tokenizer.tokenize(ex_sent)
print (n_w)
```

The output for the code above is

```
['This is an example showing sentence filtration.This is how it is done,' 'in case of Python I want to learn more.' 'So,' 'that i can have some experience over it,' 'by it I mean python.\n']
```

When I try to give '.' without any space it is taking it as a word

I want the output as

```
['This is an example showing sentence filtration.' 'This is how it is done,' 'in case of Python I want to learn more.' 'So,' 'that i can have some experience over it,' 'by it I mean python.']
```

[image: Image of the code]

Comment: Could you be more specific about your question? Give some examples of inputs and desired outputs and try to say what you have tried. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi it is my first time in stackoverflow. I've tried to explain my problem hope you can answer me. Thank you

Comment: hi alvas i hope you can help me out this time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something simpler with `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> sent = "This is an example showing sentence filtration.This is how it is done, in case of Python I want to learn more. So, that i can have some experience over it, by it I mean python."
>>> re.split(r'[.,]', sent)
['This is an example showing sentence filtration', 'This is how it is done', ' in case of Python I want to learn more', ' So', ' that i can have some experience over it', ' by it I mean python', '']
```

To keep the delimiter, you can use group:

```
>>> re.split(r'([.,])', sent)
['This is an example showing sentence filtration', '.', 'This is how it is done', ',', ' in case of Python I want to learn more', '.', ' So', ',', ' that i can have some experience over it', ',', ' by it I mean python', '.', '']
```

Comment: Thank you so much alvas. but you see in this case sure it is splitting the sentence but also extracting the comma and full stop I want to retain. Also is there any way I could do in nltk

Comment: It's not hard to put it the commas and fullstops back ;P. I would suggest that you use native python libraries as much as possible if it gives you your desired output. And if you really must use nltk, generic nlp models would usually work on normally formatted news text.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you maybe can replace all commas with dots in the string and then tokenize it:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
ex_sent = "This is an example showing sentence filtration.This is how it is done, in case of Python I want to learn more. So, that i can have some experience over it, by it I mean python."

ex_sent = ex_sent.replace(",", ".")
n_w = sent_tokenize(texto2, 'english')
print(n_w)
```